# Can I simulate keypress(CTRL+F1) in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi want to simulate the press of the keys CTRL+F1 when i do click on a button. For example:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js">
        function simulateKeyPress(){

        }
    </script>

    <button class="boton3d" onclick="simulateKeyPress()"> 
           <img src="img/phone.png">       
    </button>
```

Thanks...

Comment: Have you googled? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
  var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
  e.which = 112;       // # F1 code value
  e.ctrlkey = true;     // control key pressed
  $(document).trigger(e);// trigger event on document
```

Comment: Ok Thanks but i don't understand because you use $('input').trigger(e); when i want simulate the press of CTL+F1 in os windows. This is posible??? Because your code is not work in my test.

Comment: you can use `$(document).trigger()` for that

Comment: Ok thanks i am trying this but i no idea why no work!!!!

Comment: doesn't work for me either

Answer (score 1):

you can use .keypress method : [doc](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/#keypress)

Sample :

```
$("#MyDiv").keypress();
```

Will trigger a keypress on #MyDiv. If you'd like to also select which key was pressed, you can use .trigger : [doc](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

```
var e = $.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 112}); 
$("body").trigger(e);
```

you can find all the key here : http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks, but i need simulate that when i do a click on the button simulate the press of the keys CTRl+F1 in the os Windows. And your solution i understand that is for throught an event when you press any key.

Comment: here also not working